# Exception when trying to use `ThenInclude` in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm using *Entity Framework Core* together with Repository Pattern and I'm having one issue.

I have classes `Customer`, `Company` and `Email` which, hiding things not relevant here, look like the following:

```
public class Email
{
    public int EmailId { get; protected set; }

    public string Address { get; protected set; }

    public string Description { get; protected set; }

    public Email(string address, string description)
    {
        if (string.isNullOrEmpty(address))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(address));

        if (string.isNullOrEmpty(description))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(description));

        this.Address = address;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    protected Email() { }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; protected set; }

    public IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; protected set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings are set so that there is a one-to-one association between `Customer` and `Company` while there is a one-to-many association between `Company` and `Email`.

On the `CustomersRepository` I then created the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<Customer>()
                   .Include(x => x.Company)
                       .ThenInclude(x => x.Emails)
                   as IEnumerable<Customer>;
}
```

Now then `ThenInclude` piece is giving a problem. If I try to use this method, I end up getting one execption saying that `source` is null.

I've reviewed everything but I didn't find anything wrong. It seems everything is correctly written.

The whole point is: I have entities `A`, `B`, `C` so that `A` has one of `B`, and `B` has many of `C`, and when I retrieve `A` I need to get everything associated.

What am I doing wrong here? Why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: Can't you just `.Include(x => x.Company.Emails)`?

Comment: Thanks @Will, it does work using this solution! By the way, do you know why the `ThenInclude` doesn't work? If I understood the docs that is the recommended way, but in this case it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  Never used ThenInclue, don't know how it's implemented.  Lemme look into it for a sec and add an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems related to this bug report on Github https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2274

It was reported as an IOE, then reported fixed, then it came back as a NRE, like your exception.  The issue says it's been fixed again, but I'm unsure of in what version and I don't know what version you're currently using.

(Searched for ThenInclude issues in the github repro--there's a TON.)

Sounds unstable.  Stay away from it.  You can simply avoid the issue altogether by specifying the full path of your include directly

```
muhCompaniesOrWhatevs.Include(x => x.Company.Emails);
```